# -- SQL Generating Column and fill it automatically from the other column --

Tags: sql

i need to create a query that runs like this; all employees with an education level of 18 or 20 will receive a salary increase of 1200 and their bonus will be cut in half. List the name, education level, new salary and new bonus for these employees. Use names NEW_SALARY and NEW_BONUS for the generated columns

The new salary = salary + 1200 (How can i do this?)
The new bonus = bonus/2 (How can i do this?

Comment: if you want us to do your homework, at least provide the table structure

Comment: This question shows an exceptional lack of effort and information. Can we see what you have tried so far?

Comment: The problem sounds like you're looking for an `UPDATE` statement, not *new columns*.  It's not really clear what you're trying to do, why, or where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

After assuming lot of things ::

```
   Select name ,
          ed_level ,
          case when ed_level = 18 or ed_level = 20 then Salary + 1200 else 
               salary  end as New_salary,
          case when ed_level = 18 or ed_level = 20 then bonus * 0.5 else bonus 
               end  as new_bonus

   from yourTBL
```